# Run time execution process of the function

Tags: javascript, events, runtime, callstack

I was wondering how will be the below code gets executed in runtime.
I am aware that events are handled by the browser API and hence gets popped out from the call stack. And then the callbacks are registered in the Queue by the API. And then these messages gets executed once the stack is empty.

But happens when there are multiple functions in the onclick callback function. Having both sequential and Async functions in it. Then will they again push back to the Browser API from the Queue to Call stack then again to Browser API?

How the whole below code gets executed?

```
$('#test').on(click, function() {
   console.log('start');

   //modifies the dom like add div in the html
   modifyDom();

   //http ajax call
   someAjaxCall();

   while(let i < 5) {
      console.log(i);
      i++
   }

   setTimeout(function(){ console.log('Zero Delay'); },0);


});
```

Comment: You should use promises to wait for the async call.

Comment: You made a typo: you wrote `functin` instead of `function` in `setTimeout(functin(){ console.log('Zero Delay'); },0);`

Comment: @SLaks yes I know but I was wondering how the whole process gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

let's add line numbers to track the execution

```
01 $('#test').on(click, function() {
02    console.log('start');
03 
04    modifyDom();
05 
06    someAjaxCall();
07 
08    while(let i < 5) {
09       console.log(i);
10       i++;
11    }
12 
13    setTimeout(
14       function(){
15          console.log('Zero Delay');
16       },
17       0
18    );
19 });
```

1. `01`: attaches the event handler
2. wait for *click* ...
3. *click*
4. `02`: print 'start' on console
5. `04`: perform DOM manipulations
6. `06`: dispatch ajax request and wait for the response on networking thread (not the main thread)
7. `08-11`

   1. `i` is 0
   2. `i` is 1
   3. `i` is 2
   4. `i` is 3
   5. `i` is 4
8. `13-18`: add callback `14-16` to the timer thread (not the main thread)
9. wait for threads to return control ...

---

now, any following can happen:

1. ajax and/or timeout "return" before finishing the previous executions
2. ajax "return" before timeout
3. timeout "return" before ajax

in case 1, the main thread doesn't care about what "returned" at all since it is a single continuous stack of synchronous instructions. this means that case 1 ultimately resolves to cases 2 & 3

in cases 2 & 3, since promise microtasks take priority over timer threads, ajax "return" is promised first and then the timeout callback happens

---

#### Edit 1

I **highly recommend** watching [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1kqx6AenYw) on the topic of event loop basics and beyond since it explains the interaction of sync-code, timers, promises and much more

Answer (score 0):

What you've said about call stacks and queues are correct. JavaScript will execute all of the synchronous code and add asynchronous calls into a queue. The `setTimeout` declares when it is able to be executed up front. If there are no tasks waiting in the queue it will be called after the call stack has been cleared at the minimum time provided, which in this case is zero. The delay argument for `setTimeout` does not guarantee that will execute at that time but is a minimum value for when it can. This is because of existing items in the queue that have to be cleared first before this can be handled.

The event handlers for network calls, like your `someAjaxCall` function, are also callbacks. The listeners for the Ajax call are basically pending and not added to the queue until the relevant event occurs (like `progress`, `error`, or `success`). Still they are exactly the same as `setTimeout` and will trigger a callback through the queue.

One thing that might help clear this up a bit is the `async` and `await` syntax. By declaring your function asynchronous you can better handle asynchronous tasks in your workflow. For instance, if you need to have your Ajax call handled before continuing you could do something like this:

```
// declaring function with async tag
$('#test').on(click, async function() {
   console.log('start');

   //modifies the dom like add div in the html
   modifyDom();

   //http ajax call
   try {
       let response = await someAjaxCall(); 
       console.log('data!', response);
   } catch(err){
       console.log('network error!', err);
   }


   while(let i < 5) {
      console.log(i);
      i++
   }

   setTimeout(function(){ console.log('Zero Delay'); },0);


});

function someAjaxCall(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       $.ajax({
           url:'someUrl',
           type:'GET',
           success:function(response){
               resolve(response); 
           },
           error:function(err){
               reject(err);
           }
       })
    })
}
```

In this example the while function is awaiting the response of `someAjaxCall` within a try/catch block. The execution of the rest of the function is delayed until that function resolves or rejects. With this setup you will see this log out:

```
// start
// either 'data!', with the {response} or 'network error!', with the {error}
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4
// 5
/*
    call stack has ended
    the function will return undefined because there is nothing being returned
    all queues are assessed from oldest to youngest.
    only the setTimeout is in the queue so it's callback is executed
*/
//'Zero Delay'
```

**Update**

Additionally if you need to measure the time your function takes to execute you can use `console.time` and `console.timeEnd`(documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time)). By adding `console.time` with some label, like `console.time('Click time')` at the beginning of your function, you can add `console.timeEnd('Click time')` in another position to see exactly how long it took to run between those points (like from the beginning of the click function till the callback of the `setTimeout`).

Answer (score -2):

After clicking on `#test`, you'll have:

1. `console.log('start');` executed directly after entering the callback
2. `modifyDom()` is next. It's executed synchronously too.
3. `someAjaxCall();`. Here the request will be sent directly, then its own callback will handle the response when it eventually receives it (asynchronous)
4. `while loop` runs synchronously
5. `setTimeout` While this normally runs asynchronously (after a certain timeout), you have assigned a delay of 0. So it will runs directly after calling it.